# Sharepoint foundation 2010 2 tier installation- machines on workgroup, not on domain

Tags: sharepoint-2010, installation

I am trying to install sharepoint 2010 foundation. I want to have farm content database on a different machine which is not on a domain, but in a workgroup.
When I do a server farm installation, on 'specify database settings' screen, it asks for a domain account. The problem is that my db machine is not on a domain. Is there any way to install sharepoint with this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no, I don't believe you can. You can get away with installing SharePoint 2010 as a single-server standalone configuration in a workgroup, using local accounts for services. To add other servers to form a multiple-server farm, you need a domain environment.

The most straight forward way to do this is have a second server acting as a domain controller and have both servers in their own network. You could try having SHarePoint, SQL and DC all running on the same server, but this might be too much for one server to handle.